# Python Bottle app in /app1 - am I forced to prepend "/app1" to all routes?

Tags: python-3.x, mod-wsgi, bottle

I developed a bottle app locally using run() with routes that all start with "/" per the tutorial and now I want to put it on a real server.

Docs at http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html suggest to use `WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/yourapp/app.wsgi`, but I don't want the root of my site to be handled by a WSGI app. I want the root of the site to be handled by raw Apache, and only URLs under /app1 to be handled by WSGI.

So I set mine up as `WSGIScriptAlias /app1 /var/www/app1/app1.py`. It runs in the sense that I can see what I defined in the .py file under route('/') when I browse to server://app1, but none of the hyperlinks have /app1 prepended and the browser can't pick up my css files from /var/www/app1/css, etc.

Subject says it all. Am I forced to prepend "/app1" to all routes when I want the app to live in a subdirectory?

I was trying to future-proof myself because I foresee making /app2, /app3, etc. in future.

**EDIT 1**: For the sake of experimentation, I *did* try prepending /app1 to all routes. The result was even worse: every single address I try to browse to under /app1 gives a 404 error.

Comment: This is a API project or HTML based project?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It uses the typical pattern:
@route('/page/<var>')
def do_page(var)
    return template('pagetemplate',var)

Comment: I mean are you serving HTML pages or REST API ?

Comment: Both. Mostly pages, but a couple routes return {success:1} which Bottle sends back as json.

Comment: I think you need to use this in your `app.wsgi` https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.Bottle.mount

Comment: Those docs imply you must have a parent app and child app. I don't have a parent-child scenario.

Comment: I am looking at a possible setup, will get back soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to attempt this, I took a boilerplate code from below repo

https://github.com/arsho/bottle-bootstrap

And used that as a base. I figured out that it is possible to mount your app on a base url, if you follow few simple rules

- Each HTML that you serve should define a base path using the `HEAD` tag. Like `<base href="{{ APP_MOUNT_PATH }}">`
- The static references which needs to be relative to the base path should not start with `/` or `./`. Like `<script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery.min.js"></script>`. This will make sure the path is generated using the mount path your provided in the `base` tag
- Take the mount path from the environment variables when starting the app

So here are the updated files

**index.tpl**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Bottle web project template">
    <meta name="author" content="datamate">
    <link rel="icon" href="static/favicon.ico"> 
    <base href="{{ APP_MOUNT_PATH }}">
    <title>Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="navbar/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./">Github</a></li>
                        <li><a href="navbar-fixed-top/">Stackoverflow</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>Welcome from {{data["developer_name"]}}</h2>
                <p>This is a template showcasing the optional theme stylesheet included in Bootstrap. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique by building on or modifying it.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--./row-->
        <div class="row">
            <hr>
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; 2017 {{data["developer_organization"]}}.</p>
            </footer>           
        </div>
    </div> 
    <!-- /container -->
</body>
</html>
```

**app.py**

```
from bottle import Bottle, run, \
     template, debug, static_file

import os, sys

dirname = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Bottle()
debug(True)

@app.route('/static/<filename:re:.*\.css>')
def send_css(filename):
    print("Sending", filename, dirname)
    return static_file(filename, root=dirname+'/static/asset/css')

@app.route('/static/<filename:re:.*\.js>')
def send_js(filename):
    print("Sending", filename, dirname)
    return static_file(filename, root=dirname+'/static/asset/js')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = {"developer_name":"Tarun Lalwani",
            "developer_organization":""}
    return template('index', data = data)

@app.route('/tarun/')
def tarun():
    data = {"developer_name":"Tarun Lalwani",
            "developer_organization":""}
    return template('index', data = data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(app, host='localhost', port = 8080)
```

**app.wsgi**

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

import bottle
from app import app
application = bottle.default_app()

mount_path = os.getenv("APP_MOUNT_PATH", "/")
application.config['APP_MOUNT_PATH'] = mount_path

application.mount(mount_path,  app)
bottle.BaseTemplate.defaults['APP_MOUNT_PATH'] = mount_path
```

And then I ran it using `uwsgi`

```
[uwsgi]
http = 127.0.0.1:3031
chdir = /Users/tarunlalwani/Documents/Projects/SO/bottle-bootstrap
pythonpath = .
env = APP_MOUNT_PATH=/app2/
wsgi-file = app.wsgi
processes = 1
threads = 1
stats = 127.0.0.1:9191
; logto = ./uwsgi.log
```

Now the app loads fine at `http://localhost:3031/app2/` and ``http://localhost:3031/app2/tarun` which shows that base path works for both types of url

[image: Base URL]

[image: Base URL + One Level]

All the code is available at below repo for your convenience

https://github.com/tarunlalwani/python-bottle-base-url

Comment: You get the credit because you proved it CAN work. Feels kludgy, though. That is probably more lack of experience on my part that reality, though.

Comment: Creating a separate apache VirtualHost for app1.example.com and just living with stuff NOT being in a subdirectory was much less headache and seemed to be a more friction-free way to do this, for good or ill.

Answer (score 0):

Your WSGI application code needs to take into consideration the `SCRIPT_NAME` variable passed in the WSGI request environ when doing construction of redirect URLs etc. See:

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#url-reconstruction

Usually the WSGI framework would provide a helper function to do this. If Bottle doesn't provide such a function, you will need to implement your own.

If you have separate static files, you need to tell Apache to host them using an appropriate `Alias` directive.